# Is anyone else's Microsoft Academic Knowledge API giving a error 500? 10/07/2016

Tags: javascript, api, server, xmlhttprequest

I have been using the Microsoft Academic Knowledge API (Evaluate and Interpret), and it has been working properly for the past week, but now it is giving an error 500. I know it mean there is an error on with the server, but nothing specifically.

**Response:**
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.projectoxford.ai/academic/v1.0/interpret?query=brain&model=latest&count=10&offset=0. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500."

Anyone else having this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Odd that you get a 500 error and CORS errors - though, maybe not that odd - though that URL is giving 401 error

Comment: Just tried using the api console on the Microsoft website and its giving a 500 error too. There server must be down